# Error while inserting date to Mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a table with several columns. One of the columns has the type DATE. When I try to insert a data to the table, I get me the following error:

```
{"code":"ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE","errno":1292,"sqlMessage":"Incorrect date value: '11-04-2020' for column 'date' at row 1","sqlState":"22007","index":0,"sql":"INSERT INTO `players` (achternaam, telefoonnummer, adres, email, typetaart, aantalpersonen, smaak, vulling, opmerking, prijs, reeds_voldaan, nog_te_voldoen, date, image, user_name) VALUES ('Ashoti', '33', 'test', 'w_emanual@hotmail.com', 'Verjaardagstaart', '20', 'Vanillia smaak','Chocolade vulling', 'undefined', '100', '20', '80', '11-04-2020', '11.jpeg', '11')"}
```

I have a jQuery datepicker. Here is my add page

```
<%- include ('partials/header.ejs'); -%>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <!--<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon">-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#date").datepicker({
                formatDate: "yy-mm-dd",
                dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",

                // dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
                // dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate: 0,
                gotoCurrent: true,
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<div class="container">
    <% if (message != '') { %>
        <p class="text-center text-danger"><%= message %></p>
    <% } %>
    <form class="add-player-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="achternaam" id="achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefoonnummer" id="telefoonnummer" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Number" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="adres" id="adres" placeholder="Adres" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <h1>Reservering informatie</h1>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <select id="typetaart" name="typetaart" class="form-control" required>
                    <option selected disabled>Selecteer typetaart</option>
                    <option>Verjaardagstaart</option>
                    <option>Verlovingstaart</option>
                    <option>Bruidstaart</option>
                    <option>Eerste heilige communie taart</option>
                    <option>Geslacht bekentenistaart</option>
                    <option>Moederdag taart</option>
                    <option>Vaderdags taart</option>
                    <option>Cupcakes</option>
                    <option>Overige</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="aantalpersonen" id="aantalpersonen" placeholder="Aantalpersonen" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <select id="smaak" name="smaak" class="form-control" required>
                    <option selected disabled>Smaak</option>
                    <option>Vanillia smaak</option>
                    <option>Chocolade smaak</option>
                    <option>Citroen smaak</option>
                    <option>Mokka smaak</option>
                    <option>Anders, zie opmerkingen</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <select id="vulling" name="vulling" class="form-control" required>
                    <option selected disabled>Smaak</option>
                    <option>Vanillia vulling</option>
                    <option>Chocolade vulling</option>
                    <option>Citroen vulling</option>
                    <option>Anders, zie opmerkingen</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="opmerkingen" id="opmerkingen" placeholder="Opmerkingen" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prijs" id="prijs" placeholder="Prijs" required >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reedsVoldaan" id="reedsVoldaan" placeholder="Reeds voldaan" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nogTeVoldoen" id="nogTeVoldoen" placeholder="Nog te voldoen" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date"> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="player-img"><b>Player Image</b></label><br>
                <input type="file" name="image" id="player-img" class="" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Add Player</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my INSERT query looks like

```
"INSERT INTO `players` (achternaam, telefoonnummer, adres, email, typetaart, aantalpersonen, smaak, vulling, opmerking, prijs, reeds_voldaan, nog_te_voldoen, date, image, user_name) VALUES ('" + achternaam + "', '" + telefoonnummer + "', '" + adres + "', '" + email + "', '" + typetaart + "', '" + aantalpersonen + "', '" + smaak + "','" + vulling + "', '" + opmerking + "', '" + prijs + "', '" + reedsVoldaan + "', '" + nogTeVoldoen + "', '" + date + "', '" + image_name + "', '" + username + "')";
```

I have tried to change the formatDate but it didnt work. Can someone helps me with this and tell me how the insert query should look like to insert a date into Mysql database. Some solutions on internet say that I have to add a function STR_TO_DAT to convert the date into yyyy-mm-dd for insertion into Mysql database. But I still dont know how and where to add that function. It would be greatful if you can help me with the solution. 
Kind regards,
William Ashoti

Comment: try adding the format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Yep, see about the date data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `STR_TO_DATE` function in you `INSERT` query like this:

```
...
    STR_TO_DATE ('" + date + "', '%d-%m-%Y'),
...
```

More info about [STR_TO_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp)

Comment: Hi tcadidot0, Thank you for the help. It works. But Iam getting now a string like this Wed May 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00). How can I Only manage the date and without the time. Like this May 20 2020

Comment: I doubt that when you do the conversion above you'll get `Wed May 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)` inserted into the database.. are you talking about the date appearance in the app?

Comment: @WilliamAshoti , you can try using [toDateString method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp) . Here an [example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmuchpt8/)

Comment: While perhaps technically correct, you should be advocating that the OP use a prepared statement.